# Group by group of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a huge DB in PostgreSQL. (Sorry if this is not redacted properly, I've been trying this for hours and still working on it)

This is part of structure of the table used for my query: (table user_activities) with some sample data.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id             | activity            | operation           |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1                   | 1                   | 1                   |
| 1                   | 1                   | 1                   |
| 1                   | 1                   | 1                   |
| 2                   | 1                   | 2                   |
| 2                   | 1                   | 3                   |
| 3                   | 1                   | 3                   |
| 4                   | 1                   | 4                   |
| 4                   | 1                   | 4                   |
| 5                   | 1                   | 4                   |
| 5                   | 1                   | 5                   |
| 6                   | 3                   | 1                   |
| 6                   | 3                   | 1                   |
| 6                   | 3                   | 2                   |
| 7                   | 3                   | 3                   |
| 8                   | 3                   | 4                   |
| 8                   | 3                   | 5                   |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And this is my desired output:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| count(user_id)      | activity            | operation           |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 4                   | 1                   | 1,2                 |
| 6                   | 1                   | 3,4,5               |
| 6                   | 3                   | 1,2,3,4,5           |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to count user_id for each activity and group of operations values. So I need to group by activity when activity is 1 or 3. (already done it `WHERE activity IN (1,3)`). But I also need to group by operation. The problem is that every group of operation will have more than 1 value. Operation can be 1,2,3,4 and 5. And I want to concatenate the groups of 1,2 and also the groups of 3,4,5. But that's not all...

If I group by operation, then I'll have 5 groups for each activity. I need to have 2 groups for activity 1 (the groups already specified) and only one group with all operation values if activity is 3.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**
I won't be able to check the answers now, I hope to be able tomorrow. So will give my votes and replies for that answers then, thanks for helping.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results (to clarify what you are looking for) and the query you currently have (to help anyone else writing a query).

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok, give me a minute, editing

Comment: Can you use the tablefunc extension?

Comment: Check your sample. Activity 1 doesnt have operation 5, and activity 3 only have `1,3,5`

Comment: @dtelaroli dont know what is that... I will give a look at that, but meanwhile I will try to solve this without it

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Its just a sample, I gave all the cases, with that information is enough for my purpose

Comment: I know is a sample, but if the sample is wrong we make the wrong solution. Please fix the sample, would you?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza There you go, I think the sample is complete now, tell if it isnt and will edit again, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46e1f/8)

Just use a CASE to put together the groups you want.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT "user_id", "activity", "operation",
        CASE 
             WHEN "activity" = 1 THEN 
                   CASE 
                       WHEN "operation" IN (1,2) THEN '1_first'        
                       ELSE '1_second'
                   END 
             WHEN "activity" = 3 THEN '3_first'
        END as "op_group"
    FROM user_activities
)
SELECT "activity", 
       "op_group", 
        count("user_id"), 
        array_agg(distinct "operation") as "operation"
FROM cte
GROUP BY "activity", "op_group"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| activity | op_group | count | operation |
|----------|----------|-------|-----------|
|        1 |  1_first |     4 |       1,2 |
|        1 | 1_second |     6 |     3,4,5 |
|        3 |  3_first |     6 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
```

Comment: I have a question... is it possible to use `WHEN "operation" IN (1,2)` instead of `WHEN "operation" = 1 OR "operation" = 2`?

Comment: yes, i update my answer and the fiddle with that change

Answer (score 2):

Updated for your detailed specification:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, ua.activity, array_agg(distinct ua.operation)
FROM users ua
JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 1 as operation, 1 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 2 as operation, 1 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 3 as operation, 2 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 4 as operation, 2 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 5 as operation, 2 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 1 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 2 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 3 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 4 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 5 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
) c
ON ua.activity = c.activity and ua.operation = c.operation
GROUP BY c.GROUP_CODE, ua.activity
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46e1f/15

---

**original answer**

This is how I would do it, below I create the logic table dynamically but you can also have the table in your database and join to it.

```
SELECT GROUP_CODE, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM user_activities ua
JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 1 as operation, 1 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 2 as operation, 1 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 3 as operation, 2 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 4 as operation, 2 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS activity, 5 as operation, 2 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 1 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 2 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 3 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 4 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS activity, 5 as operation, 3 as GROUP_CODE
) c
ON ua.activity = c.activity and ua.operation = c.operation
GROUP BY GROUP_CODE
```

This should be quite fast -- remember SQL is designed to work with sets (tables) and joins -- this uses joins to perform the logic.  It is also nice because if you make it a table you can change the logic just by changing the table OR have multiple "logics" stored in the table if you add another column to select on and then pick which one to use as the query runs.

I've used similar methods to do weighted and personalized ordering in dynamic UIs.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, a query like this would help you. Information in the questions and comments have confused me a little, so I am using my best judgement to provide a solution

```
create table test (user_id int, activity int, operation int);
insert into test values (1,1,1), (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (2,1,3), (2,1,4), (3,3,1), (4,3,3), (4,3,5);

select count(*), activity, array_agg(operation)
from test
group by activity, user_id

Result:
| count | activity | array_agg | 
| 3     | 1        | {1,1,2}   | 
| 2     | 1        | {3,4}     | 
| 1     | 3        | {1}       | 
| 2     | 3        | {3,5}     |
```

Based on the edited question, I feel this is how I'd solve it:

Table:

```
create table test (user_id int, activity int, operation int);
insert into test values 
(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),
(2,1,2),(2,1,3),
(3,1,3),
(4,1,4),(4,1,4),
(5,1,4),(5,1,5),
(6,3,1),(6,3,1),(6,3,2),
(7,3,3),
(8,3,4),(8,3,5);
```

Query:

```
select count(*), activity, string_agg(distinct operation::VARCHAR, ',')
from test
where operation in (1,2) and activity = 1
group by activity

UNION ALL

select count(*), activity, string_agg(distinct operation::VARCHAR, ',')
from test
where operation in (3,4,5) and activity = 1
group by activity

UNION ALL

select count(*), activity, string_agg(distinct operation::VARCHAR, ',')
from test
where activity = 3
group by activity
```

Result

```
count | activity | string_agg
4     | 1        | 1,2
6     | 1        | 3,4,5
6     | 3        | 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: this is wrong.  if you group by activity and user id then you would get a unique row for each userid at a min.  There are 8 userids  and yes you are confused.

Comment: There weren't 8 userids when I last saw it, @Hogan. I will attempt to improve the answer later today.

Comment: Sorry, my bad of his confussion... I need some sleep actually. So my bad there

Comment: @AleOtero93 that's no problem. I've edited the answer based on the edits in your question.